# ACPI PCC probe failed while installing!

Tags: boot, dual-boot, kernel, live-usb, acpi

So, I've been trying to install ubuntu 14.04.03 LTS the past few days but I always face this error, when I hit install the screen turns extremly white(x32) or extremly black(x64) then I get the ACPI PCC Probe Failed then the screen stays the same for as long as it's on. I also tried live in both x32/x64 and didn't work either with the same problem. I tried to boot live a Kali Linux and it worked fine(version 1.1 not 2.0). I don't know what information I should provide as I already made several searches and some said it's related to GPU and some said it's related to the bios mode and some said it's a harmless error and will disappear after few attempts which hasn't happened yet, hopefully someone can help me.

Comment: try to change boot option with  `nomodeset noapic`.

Comment: How do I do that? Since I'm actually trying to INSTALL the system.

Answer (score 1):

I am facing the same problem. I have tried huge number of things. At last I changed my graphics card with lower version which was old one. That solved the problem. I guess it was an issue with the graphics card (GPU).